# How to convert a property of class base on its type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am integrating an application with another application. I have a problem where Application B receives a response from Application A via a Rest request.

The object I am getting is of DiscountCodeNode type:

```
public class DiscountCodeNode {

   public DiscountCode codeDiscount { get; set; }
   public string id { get; set; }
}
```

The possible chance of DiscountCode type could be of `DiscountCodeApp`, `DiscountCodeBasic`, `DiscountCodeBxgy`, `DiscountCodeFreeShipping`.

How do I know the type of DiscountCode while deserializing the object into `DiscountCodeNode`

I tried making the `codeDiscount` type `object` but again how do I know what type of this object is so, that I can typecast ?

Comment: can you implement an interface between the code clases?, something like `IDIscountCode`,  after that you can do pattern matching

Comment: You don't have to convert anything. The deserializer will take care of that as long as you have the same Enum list.  ps the enum is stored as an integer in the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interface implementacion is the way to go, i would implement an interface between the `Discount` Classes and i would force the `DiscountNode` class to implement the interface, you can find an example below:

```
using System;


namespace StackOverflow
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var discountCodeBxgy = new DiscountCodeBxgy() { Code = "Bxgy" };

            var discountCodeNode = new DiscountCodeNode { Id = "MyId", CodeDiscount = discountCodeBxgy };

            if (discountCodeNode.CodeDiscount is DiscountCodeBxgy Bxgy)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Bxgy.Code);
            }
            // Just to prove it is right! --> this message will not be shown in the console app
            if (discountCodeNode.CodeDiscount is DiscountCodeApp App)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(App.Code);

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

       
    }

    internal class DiscountCodeNode
    {
        public IDiscountCode CodeDiscount { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    internal class DiscountCodeApp : IDiscountCode
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }

    }

    internal class DiscountCodeBasic : IDiscountCode
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }

    }

    internal class DiscountCodeBxgy: IDiscountCode
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }

    }

    internal class DiscountCodeFreeShipping : IDiscountCode
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }

    }
    internal interface IDiscountCode
    {
        string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

At the end you will have in the console the output "Bxgy" because of the pattern matching, that means it has worked, as show in the following image:
[image: Console Output]

I hope it helps

Regards

Miguel